# Troubleshooting "import arcpy" command?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, installation, numpy, importerror

This is the first time im using python/arcpy. I keep getting an error with `import arcpy` command.

Can anyone help me find out why?

```
import arcpy
```

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 1, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy__init__.py", line 24, in
>   
>       from arcpy.toolbox import *   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\toolbox.py", line 359, in
>   
>       from .management import Graph, GraphTemplate   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 26, in
>   
>       import _management   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy_management.py", line 14, in
>   
>       import _graph   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy_graph.py", line 27, in

```
import numpy
```

> ImportError: No module named numpy

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Question and Answer format.  I've seen similar questions here in the past (although I haven't found them yet) and I recall them being along the lines of incorrectly installed Arcpy or incorrect Python versions installed.  Check your arcpy and python installs match your ArcGIS version.

Comment: Have you to installed/updated numpy, scipy, pandas? These often cause ArcPy to break, because they use a different version of numpy than ArcPy does.

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195663/cannot-import-arcpy-in-arcgis-10-3-1

Comment: Which IDE do you use? ArcGIS by default uses python 2.7 version. Do you install another version?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find an Python 2.7 IDLE installed with your ArcGIS:

[image]

Calling `import arcpy` using this Python version will work!